# How to get colors displayed into game I am making?

Tags: python, linux, colors, pygame, linux-mint

This is the first time I am using Pygame. And I am just starting to learn programming. At the moment I learning for about 4 to 7 months.

I followed the tutorial for the game I am making. (How to Program a Game! (in Python) by Keith Galli)

Unfortenately the colors will not be displayed in the game. So at the moment I am just staring at a black 'box'.

The game is a kind of 'space invaders'-game. So there are blue bricks falling from the top of the 'box', but at the moment you don see them.

---

Because I am jusing Linux Mint as my OS, I thought: mayby I need other code for the colours.

I tried ANSI code:

```
# ANSI escae code for colours:
#RED = "\e[0;31m"
#BLUE = "\e[34mBlue"
#YELLOW= "\e[33mYellow"
#BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "\e[30m"

instead of RGB:
# RGB colours:
RED = (255, 0, 0))
BLUE = (0, 0, 255))
YELLOW= (204, 204, 0)
BACKGROUND_COLOUR = (0, 0, 0))
```

But I stil do not see anything when I run the game :(

---

Here is some code:

```
import pygame 
import random
import sys
import colorama

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

# ANSI escae code for colours:
#RED = "\e[0;31m"
#BLUE = "\e[34mBlue"
#YELLOW= "\e[33mYellow"
#BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "\e[30m"

# RGB colours:
RED = (255, 0, 0))
BLUE = (0, 0, 255))
YELLOW= (204, 204, 0)
BACKGROUND_COLOUR = (0, 0, 0))

player_size = 50
player_pos = [WIDTH/2, HEIGHT - 2 * player_size]


enemy_size = 50
enemy_pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size), 0]
enemy_list = [enemy_pos]

SPEED = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

# gameloop

game_over = False

score = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

myFont = pygame.font.sysFont("monospace", 35)

def set_level(score,SPEED):
    if score < 20:
        SPEED = 5
    elif score < 40:
        SPEED = 8
    elif score < 60:
        SPEED = 12
    else:
        SPEED = 18
    return SPEED

# SPEED = score / 5 +1
# return SPEED

def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
    delay = random.random()
    if len(enemy_list) < 10 and delay < 0.1:
    x_pos = random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size)
        y_pos = 0
        enemy_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])


def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
    for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1],
        enemy_size, enemy_size))
```

---

I hope to see the bricks in the game.
Whick colorcoding to use... and how to implement these?

Blue for the ones falling from the sky, red for the player itself.

Comment: There is a typo in your code `pygame.font.sysFont` has to be `pygame.font.SysFont`

Comment: where is your game loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a main loop, which does the following:

- clear the screen with the back ground color ([`pygame.Surface.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill))
- draw all the objects
- update the display ([`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip))

e.g.:

```py
run = True
while run:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

   screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
   draw_enemies(enemy_list)
   pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to see if I get the game working :)

Comment: I got the game working, thanks to all of your comments!
Thank you!